# Resubmit approval process if record edited?

Tags: approval-process

I have a scenario where the user has submitted record for approval and record got locked. In the mid of the approval, another user edits the record. **In this case users need to re submit the record for approval.**

How can I achieve this?

In the approval process, on each step I am changing the 'Status' Field in the record. I am resetting the 'Status' to pending on record edit. in this case, 'Submit for approval' button is not visible in the record.

Please advise.

Additional Info:

we have 4 step approval process.

- User submits the record for approval.
- Approver 01, approves the record and it goes to approvar 02.
- Meanwhile submitter edits the record. for example: changed the Amount field.
- The record should be resubmitted for approval. it should go to the all the approval steps again.

I hope it will help.

Other option i found is Submitter can recall the approval and edit the record, then he can resubmit for the approval. but is there any automated way of doing this?

Comment: Who exactly has to re submit the record the second time after edit and to who ? to next approver?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in the mid of approval'? Would not the record be still locked, if its not approved? Please explain!

Comment: - User submits the record for approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is :

1) Submitter1 edit and submit the record to Approver1

2.1) Approver1 review/edit record and then must **Approve** --> the record is going to Approver2. Your record will still be in "Pending" for Approver2

2.2) Approver1 reject --> go to final reject actions, unlock records and Submitter1 will have to submit again

3.1) Approver2 approves --> your record is now approved, do whatever you want (field update, email alert)

3.2) Approver2 rejects --> you have 2 options here, go back to step1(=Approver1) OR go to final reject actions. In final reject actions you can unlock your record(+ field updates), so the oirignal submitter can edit and submit again.

Of course in your approval process setting, you must to enable "System Admin AND approver can edit records"

I hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Scenario - Account record has an approval process in place. Once it is approved.
If any one of two specific fields (like industry or phone) are updated, then I have a record triggered flow which should lock the record and go for submit for approval.
In flow, I have mentioned Criteria - phone isChanged True OR Industyr isChanged true

Issue - Record is getting locked but not getting submitted. In flow debug run , its runs successfully. can someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you do, include more details of the Flow.